# Cropping and masking Rasta Data and converting it to a vector

Tags: r, geospatial, terra

I am trying to crop and mask raster data and convert the raster data to a vector and to an sf object with terra. However, I always get the following error message: Error in UseMethod `("st_as_sf")` not applicable method for `'st_as_sf'` applied to object of class `"SpatVector"`. I would appreciate any help or advice to overcome this hurdle.

My code looks as follows

```
packs <- list("sf", "tidyverse", "terra")
lapply(packs, require, character.only=TRUE)

pop_count <- rast(raster.path)
adm_ner_sf <- st_read(shp.path)

pop_afg_sf <- pop_count %>%
  crop(vect(adm_afg_sf)) %>%
  mask(vect(adm_afg_sf)) %>%
  as.points() %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  rename(pop_count = gpw_v4_population_count_rev11_2010_2pt5_min)
```

I am using SEDAC population density raster data (Formal class SpatRaster), which I am trying to limit to the shape of Afghanistan, by using an Afghanistan shape file (adm_afg_sf).

Any feedback would be greatly appeciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you do is as equivalent to the minimal self-contained reproducible example below and that works:

```
library(terra)
library(sf)

f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
p <- as.points(r)
s <- st_as_sf(p)
```

Perhaps you have old versions of `sf` and/or `terra`? Try `update.packages()`